# Wordpress XML-RPC Read-Only App for Android

Tags: android, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am developing and Android app to view the posts on my blog. I am using [XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) of Wordpress. It [requires a user name and password](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#Parameters_2) for even reading posts.

I don't find it secure to put an admin/editor password into the code. But, if I use the credentials of a user of other roles, it can't read the whole list.

What is the secure way of making a **read-only** app for Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Use the RSS Feed provided by WordPress instead of the XML-RPC API.

you can get the feed for your blog by adding /feed to your blog url.

for example:
Blog URL: http://this.ismysite.com/wordpress/
Feed URL: http://this.ismysite.com/wordpress/feed

Real example
Blog URL: http://blog.wpde.org/ 
Feed URL: http://blog.wpde.org/feed

Comment: with RSS you can get only the latest posts. I want to display previous messages as well. and I want to make pages which display posts in separate categories.

Comment: I'm a couple years late, but append '?paged=2' and so forth to get the rest of the posts of a Wordpress blog. Although it doesn't work for comment feeds which is a royal pain for me currently. And I don't want ot scrape the HTML for it.